# PyQt4 QStandardItem need setInputMask

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a QTreeView (100 rows) with QStandardItemModel (10 columns) 
Each table cell has data inserted as QStandardItem 
In the second column, I need the following mask "0-00-00-0-0000" but QStandardItem does not have a setInputMask("0-00-00-0-0000") method available. 
How do I do this, and is there a better way of getting this done, maybe with QTableWidget?

```
self.model = QStandardItemModel(self)
self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(header)

self.table = QTreeView()
self.table.setModel(self.model)

row=[]
for item in items:
    row.append( QStandardItem(item) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create custom `Item Delegate` by sublclassing [`QItemDelegate`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemdelegate.html) which will create editor with mask, and then use [`setItemDelegateForColumn`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegateForColumn)

Delegate class:

```
class MaskInputDelegate(QItemDelegate):

    def __init__(self, mask, parent=None):
        QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)
        self._mask = mask

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QLineEdit(parent)
        editor.setInputMask(self._mask)
        return editor
```

Usage:

```
self.table.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, MaskInputDelegate('0-00-00-0-0000'))
```

> Is there a better way of getting this done, maybe with QTableWidget?

Same solution works for `QTableWidget`.